# nib-less iOS app has no user interaction

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a test app for iOS that is built without any nib/xib files.  It runs, the UIViewController is made root and displayed on the screen with one button, but that button is not clickable.  Also, a UITapGestureRecognizer placed on the UIViewController's view property doesn't ever fire.  I can't figure out why, so I placed my project in dropbox, hoping someone here knows what the problem is.

The project is simple, just a UIViewController template minus the nib files, the main and plist files edited to reflect this, and then a button and gesture recognizer added.  Nuthin fires:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3905723/ios/blarggesture.zip

Comment: The answer from @rckoenes does the trick. But may I ask, why would you go through this trouble, if you could just keep the MainWindow.xib around and do the rest of the app just in code?

Comment: @miamk It comes out of striving for a clean project layout, without files I don't look at.  I don't use the interface builder, so I I try not to have nib files laying around.  Also, I'll make a template out of it so that every project I make starts without nibs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell your window what its frame is:

```
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame] autorelease];
```

Just ask UIScreen for the appplication frame will do, just like the code above.